# Calling super method in Django TestCase causes RecursionError

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-unittest, django-unittest

According to [Django's document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#simpletestcase):

> #### Warning
>
> **SimpleTestCase** and its subclasses (e.g. **TestCase**, ...) rely on **setUpClass()** and **tearDownClass()** to perform some class-wide initialization (e.g. overriding settings). If you need to override
> those methods, don’t forget to call the **super** implementation:
>
> ```
> class MyTestCase(TestCase):
>
>     @classmethod
>     def setUpClass(cls):
>         super(MyTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
>         ...
>
>     @classmethod
>     def tearDownClass(cls):
>         ...
>         super(MyTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()
> ```
>
> ......

I decided to follow this practice when writing tests:

```
class AuthorListViewTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        number_of_authors = 13
        for author_num in range(number_of_authors):
            Author.objects.create(first_name='Christian %s' % author_num, last_name='Surname %s' % author_num,)
        super(AuthorListViewTest, cls).setUpTestData()

    # testing functions
```

But I get an `RecursionError` when running tests:

```
  <hundreds of identical lines omitted>
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1025, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Documents/Projects/locallibrary/catalog/tests/test_models.py", line 10, in setUpTestData
    super(AuthorModelTest, cls).setUpClass()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1025, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Documents/Projects/locallibrary/catalog/tests/test_models.py", line 10, in setUpTestData
    super(AuthorModelTest, cls).setUpClass()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1025, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Documents/Projects/locallibrary/catalog/tests/test_models.py", line 10, in setUpTestData
    super(AuthorModelTest, cls).setUpClass()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1025, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Documents/Projects/locallibrary/catalog/tests/test_models.py", line 10, in setUpTestData
    super(AuthorModelTest, cls).setUpClass()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1025, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Documents/Projects/locallibrary/catalog/tests/test_models.py", line 10, in setUpTestData
    super(AuthorModelTest, cls).setUpClass()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1025, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Documents/Projects/locallibrary/catalog/tests/test_models.py", line 10, in setUpTestData
    super(AuthorModelTest, cls).setUpClass()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1025, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Documents/Projects/locallibrary/catalog/tests/test_models.py", line 10, in setUpTestData
    super(AuthorModelTest, cls).setUpClass()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1025, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Documents/Projects/locallibrary/catalog/tests/test_models.py", line 10, in setUpTestData
    super(AuthorModelTest, cls).setUpClass()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1025, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Documents/Projects/locallibrary/catalog/tests/test_models.py", line 10, in setUpTestData
    super(AuthorModelTest, cls).setUpClass()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1025, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Documents/Projects/locallibrary/catalog/tests/test_models.py", line 10, in setUpTestData
    super(AuthorModelTest, cls).setUpClass()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1025, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Documents/Projects/locallibrary/catalog/tests/test_models.py", line 9, in setUpTestData
    Author.objects.create(first_name='Big', last_name='Bob')
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 947, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1043, in _insert
    query = sql.InsertQuery(self.model)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 177, in __init__
    super(InsertQuery, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.where = where()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

This error fixed after removing the `super` line.

Why is it? Should I stop calling the super implementation, which is suggested by the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the traceback, it seems the `setUpTestData` calls `setUpClass` in parent class. But your code snippet calls `setUpTestData` instead, which is correct.

Comment: Oh stupid me! I think there was a typo in my code and you just find it. Going to delete this unconstructive question...(Edit: I got a warning saying that `Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking`, so I will leave it be)